# Unknown component on PCB - rectangular, white, 4 terminals, marked 3215

Tags: identification, components

I found a component, which I couldn't recognize, on a printed circuit board.  Does anyone know this kind of component?

**Edited** :The unknown components are the white squared ones. There are many of them.

The person that ask me this didn't tell me what this circuit does.

I attached a photo to help in the recognition:

[image: Unknown component]

Comment: The array of white boxes with 4 terminals each might be optocouplers of some sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an optocoupler. Confirmed by typing "3215 optocoupler" into google.

[image]